# Vscode on Windows 10 - failed to launch path to executable shell for Julia 1.5.3

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

I am having a difficult time to get Vscode to work with Julia 1.53 after I upgraded from Julia 1.5.2. I am sure it is due to my settings but I cannot find examples of how to fix. When I start Vscode now I cannot run any Julia scripts. Just hangs at "Starting Julia Language Server ...." in the task line and on the RHS side of the task line I get: "The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia 1.5.3\bin" is not a file of a symlink." Julia path is as shown in the message above. I am thinking the problem is in the Julia: Environmental Path and the Julia: Executable Path (under preferences/settings) I can't find any examples of what to pout in these fields> Can anyone help? Perhaps a reinstall of Vscode? I have been fiddling for hours to no avail

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem the Julia: Executable pat should be  "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia 1.5.3\bin\julia.exe". Hope this is helpful so others. Peter